# R: get sum from selected Input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am relative new to R and trying to learn on my own.

I want to create in a shiny dashboard a select-field where i can choose products of my Data (.xls) and get a sum returned.

The Input is via *selectInput* and *selectize*. This is the part, which works :)

If I choose 1 product i'll get the calories of this product back...so far.

My Problem is that wanna choose more products then 1 and get the sum of the calories. How do i have to identify/search the products of the input field in my table and how do i get the sum of it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: Do you need further info about file? only two columns are important for this: product and calories.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Daten einlesen
McDaten <- read_excel("~/Desktop/McDaten.xlsx")
McDaten$kcal <- McDaten$`kcal (100g)`

ui <- dashboardPage(
skin="red",
dashboardHeader(title = "Analytics Dashboard", titleWidth = 290),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 290,
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Virtuelles Menü", tabName = "charts", icon = icon("cutlery"))

)
  ),

  dashboardBody(


tabItems(

  tabItem(tabName = "charts",
          fluidPage(
            br(),
            fluidRow(
              column(4,
                     selectInput('in6', 'Menü', McDaten$Produkt, multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)),
              column(4,infoBoxOutput("progressBox"))
            )
          )

  ))))


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$progressBox <- renderInfoBox({
    b <- McDaten %>%
  select(`kcal (Portion)`, Produkt) %>%
  filter(McDaten$Produkt %in% input$in6) %>%
  summarise(`kcal (Portion)`)

infoBox(
  "Progress", paste0(b, " kcal"), icon = icon("list"),
  color = "purple", fill = TRUE
)
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `choices = unique(McDaten$Produkt)` in the 'ui' and in `summarise` the `sum` needs to be specified for the column of interest

-ui

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin="red",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analytics Dashboard", titleWidth = 290),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Virtuelles Menü", tabName = "charts", icon = icon("cutlery"))

    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(


    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "charts",
              fluidPage(
                br(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(4,
                     selectInput('in6', 'Menü', 
                       choices = unique(McDaten$Produkt), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE )),
                  column(4,infoBoxOutput("progressBox"))
                )
              )

      ))))
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$progressBox <- renderInfoBox({
    b <- McDaten %>%
      select(`kcal (Portion)`, Produkt) %>%
      filter(Produkt %in% input$in6) %>%
      summarise(`kcal (Portion)` = sum(`kcal (Portion)`)) %>%
      pull(`kcal (Portion)`)


    infoBox(
      "Progress", paste0(b, " kcal"), icon = icon("list"),
      color = "purple", fill = TRUE
    )
  })

}
```

-run the app

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-data

```
set.seed(24)
McDaten <- data.frame(Produkt = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE),
   `kcal (Portion)` = sample(1400:2000, 30, replace = TRUE), 
        stringsAsFactors= FALSE, check.names = FALSE)

McDaten$kcal <- McDaten$`kcal (Portion)`
```

-output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Woooow it works! Thank you so much! :)

Btw great community! ;)